# instance method public int manhattanDistance(Point other) does not compile

Tags: java, return-value

Add the following method to the Point class:

```
public int manhattanDistance(Point other)
```

Returns the “Manhattan distance” between the current Point object and the given other Point object.The  Manhattan distance refers to the distance between two places if one can travel between them only by moving horizontally
or vertically, as though driving on the streets of Manhattan. In our case, the     Manhattan distance is the sum
of the absolute values of the differences in their coordinates; in other words, the difference in `x` plus the difference in
`y` between the points.

```
public class Point {
 private int x;
 private int y;

 // constructs a new point at the origin, (0, 0)
 public Point() {
 this(0, 0); // calls Point(int, int) constructor
 }

 // constructs a new point with the given (x, y) location
 public Point(int x, int y) {
 setLocation(x, y);
 }

 // returns the distance between this Point and (0, 0)
 public double distanceFromOrigin() {
 return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
 }

 // returns the x-coordinate of this point
 public int getX() {
 return x;
 }

 // returns the y-coordinate of this point
 public int getY() {
 return y;
 }

 // sets this point's (x, y) location to the given values
 public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 }

 // returns a String representation of this point
 public String toString() {
 return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
 }

 // shifts this point's location by the given amount
 public void translate(int dx, int dy) {
 setLocation(x + dx, y + dy);
 }

 public int manhattanDistance(Point other){
/// int distance = Math.abs(x-other) + Math.abs(y-other);

 return Math.abs(x - other)+ Math.abs(y - other) ;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Have you read the compile error that you get? It should point you to the line with the error and be fairly self explanatory.

Comment: @assylias ...having a hard time not pointing out the obvious... Oh no, the others just ruined it...

Comment: [Do I look like a guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Answer (score 2):

`other.getX()` instead of `other`, same for y.
Other is an instance of the Point class.
You want to access the x value of other through the getter for this value, getX.
Read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
return Math.abs(x - other)+ Math.abs(y - other);
```

The above line should be:

```
return Math.abs(x - other.getX())+ Math.abs(y - other.getY());
```

Why?

Becuase at the moment you're trying to take the point object directly from an integer, which makes no sense. Even in logical terms, you can't sensibly subtract a point in 2D space from an integer. You need to take a specific value from the integers (x and y from the `other` object, which you get by calling the appropriate methods.)

Unrelated to the issue, but you would also do well to format your code properly!

Comment: Formatting would have helped a lot indeed ^^

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong : Math.abs(x - other)+ Math.abs(y - other)

other is Point object.You have to get x and y of that Point object and then do the minus operation

Instead try this :
 return Math.abs(x - other.getX())+ Math.abs(y - othe.getY()) ;